# Angular 1.5 not update ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I display a table through ng-repeat

```
     <div ng-app="spApp">
<div ng-controller="spListCtrl as MyList">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="2">
    <thead>

        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>CellPhone</th>
        <th>Update</th>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in MyList.Contacts track by $index">

            <td class="align-center"><input type="text" ng-model="MyList.Contacts[$index].FirstName"> </input></td>
            <td class="align-center">{{MyList.Contacts[$index].Title}}</td>
            <td class="align-center">{{MyList.Contacts[$index].Email}}</td>
            <td class="align-center">{{MyList.Contacts[$index].CellPhone}}</td>
            <td class="align-center"><button ng-click="ShowNewForm(MyList.Contacts[$index])">Изменить</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Loading through the service on the ajax data

```
spApp.controller('spListCtrl', function spListCtrl($scope,dataService){

var Contacts;
var promiseObj=dataService.getContacts();
promiseObj.then(function(value) {

Contacts=value; 
 });
```

I check in debugging, and data are assigned to come normal, but not displayed. What did not tried it, tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while using `controllerAs` pattern, do bind data binding variables to `this`(controller function context), so that you could access them on HTML using it alias `MyList`(which is instance of controller function).

**Code**

```
spApp.controller('spListCtrl', function spListCtrl(dataService){
   var self =  this
   var promiseObj=dataService.getContacts();
   promiseObj.then(function(value) {
      self.Contacts=value.data; 
  });
});
```

And inside `ng-repeat` use `item` to have binding working.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in MyList.Contacts track by $index">

        <td class="align-center"><input type="text" ng-model="item.FirstName"> </input></td>
        <td class="align-center">{{item.Title}}</td>
        <td class="align-center">{{item.Email}}</td>
        <td class="align-center">{{item.CellPhone}}</td>
        <td class="align-center"><button ng-click="ShowNewForm(item)">Изменить</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Also, we can use {{item.Title}} instead of  MyList.Contacts[$index].Title. Can't we? The same goes with other properties as well.

Comment: No need to inject `$scope` when using controllerAs syntax. Also you need to access the `.data` property of the result from the promise. e.g. `self.Contacts = value.data; `.

Comment: Thank you! Everything worked.
"MyList.Contacts [$ index] .First Name" is needed in the event of the same values.

Comment: @Lex correct.. Thabks for heads up..actually i had in hurry for dinner. Otherwise i don't misss such stuff

Comment: @Alexey you should use item there..no need to access object using $index